# Ajax and Shopify Cart

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify

I'm using Shopify and I'm trying to add an item to the cart using Ajax. The code here does not add and item to my cart. I've spent 5 hours trying to fix this, but no cigar :/

I've included the wrappers in in my theme.liquid.

Here's my code:

```
<a class="chicken-fingers" onclick="fastcart('515257513','1')">Add to Cart</a>

  <script>  
  function fastcart(variantId, quantity){
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://name.myshopify.com/cart/add.js',
      data: 'quantity='+quantity+'&id='+variantId,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){
          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: '/cart.js',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(cartdata){
                  $('.cart-total-items .count').html(cartdata.item_count);
                  $('.cart-total-price').html('$'+(cartdata.total_price/100).toFixed(2));

                }
            });
        }
    });
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: Hi! It's specifically `(http://name.myshopify.com/cart/add.js)`

Comment: And, is that a different url than what is currently being used to view the page? (different subdomain, domain, or port?)

Comment: Have you opened the javascript console to see if any errors are occurring? have you been to the network tab of that console to inspect the request headers being sent/received?

Comment: That's the URL format they require you to POST to Add to Cart with Shopify.

Comment: Right, but if you removed `http://name.myshopify.com` would it still be pointing to the same location?

Comment: Ok. So I'm kind of a newb here, but that's what I was kind of confused about. In most examples it's just '/cart/add.js' but it's not clear to me how that URL would point specifically to my store.

Comment: That's what i'm asking. Is the address in the addressbar of your browser `http://name.myshopify.com`? if not, then you are trying to make a cross-origin request which requires proper CORS headers and a plugin for IE. There should be an error in your console if this is the case.

Comment: Ah. I think that's where my problem lies. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not going to work.

Cross-domain Ajax requests don't work and are not allowed. You can only send requests to your own domain name, and cannot send ajax requests to another domain.

You can try out HtmlAgilityPack if you're using ASP.NET!

Actually what `/cart/add.js` means is that it will move point to your own website's folder `cart` and the file of `add.js`. This way you will add the component! In this method, the origin is same, your request will be made through your website and will be sent to the website of yours.

If you want to save the data on their website, you need to use HTTP POST request with the data. And do the coding thing there, and then come back with a response! Or use a plugin for this.

Here are some main articles for cross-domain tutorials:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-CORS-AJAX-Requests-Between-jQuery-And-Node-js.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185506/AJAX-Cross-Origin-HTTP-request (These guys would help you much)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy (Learn here, what requests are allowed and what would fail)

Comment: *"Cross-domain Ajax requests don't work and are not allowed"* unless you correctly implement CORS.

Comment: I understand now ... for what it's worth, using Ajax is the only way to prevent a redirect to the Shpoify cart, however it appears you can only implement it _within_ Shopify. If you're trying to POST to Shopify from an external site, you're out of luck

Comment: May be it's too late, but for external sites there is https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/